# Apply operations on a one-dimensional array of instances in one line, using LINQ

Tags: linq, generics

Consider the following structures:

```
internal struct Coordinate
{
    public Double Top { get; set; }
    public Double Left { get; set; }
}

internal struct Dimension
{
    public Double Height { get; set; }
    public Double Width { get; set; }
}

internal struct Property
{
    public Boolean Visible { get; set; }
    internal String Label { get; set; }
    public String Value { get; set; }
    internal Coordinate Position { get; set; }
    public Dimension Dimensions { get; set; }
}
```

I need to manipulate 20 or so instances of *Property*. I'd like to do so as cleanly as possible... Is is possible to apply multiple operations on an array of *Property* in one line of code?

I'm thinking something along the lines of:

```
new []
{
    InstanceOfProperty,
    InstanceOfProperty,
    InstanceOfProperty ...
}.Each(p => p.Dimensions.Height = 100.0);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing this:

```
new List<Property> { InstanceOfProperty, InstanceOfProperty, ... }.ForEach((p =>
{
    p.Dimensions.Height = 0.0;
}));
```

*Note: I have converted the structures into classes. If I went with the original struct-based design; I would have had to "new up" the structures in order to change their value. Like so:*

```
new List<Property> { InstanceOfProperty, InstanceOfProperty, ... }.ForEach((p =>
{
    p.Dimensions = new Dimension { Height = 0.0 };
}));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you wrote your own `Each` method taking an `Action<T>` delegate, you could.

**Edit:**

Actually it wont work.  You are using value types. Any reason why it cant be `class`?

Both `Dimension` and `Property` would have to be reference types for that assignment to reflect after processing the list.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a `Each` extension method, but since your objects are structs, you can't make it work on an `IEnumerable<T>`. However you can make an extension method that works on an array, using a delegate with a ref parameter:

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public delegate void RefAction<T>(ref T arg);

    public static void Each<T>(this T[] array, RefAction<T> action)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        {
            action(ref array[i]);
        }
    }
}

...

new []
{
    InstanceOfProperty,
    InstanceOfProperty,
    InstanceOfProperty ...
}.Each((ref Property p) => p.Dimensions.Height = 100.0);
```

However since `Dimension` is also a struct, it won't work this way (and the compiler will detect it and give you an error). You have to do something like that instead:

```
new []
{
    InstanceOfProperty,
    InstanceOfProperty,
    InstanceOfProperty ...
}.Each((ref Property p) => p.Dimensions = new Dimension
                           {
                               Width = p.Dimensions.Width,
                               Height = 100.0
                           });
```

On the whole, everything would be *a lot* simpler if your types were classes rather than structs...

Comment: Looks neat. This was going to be my second "try". Thanks. Could you check my answer to this question and tell me if you foresee any problems?